# Calculate time of session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I want to calculate the time of a session in my web application, to be more precise, I want to have time of a user's connection to the site since its connection until disconnection or closing the window browser. Thank you for suggesting a solution for me in JavaScript or PHP, and where do I have to put the script, all the pages? or a specific page? and which table ?

Comment: Please show some effort in trying to solve this issue yourself, also please include the code you have tried in your question.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here and i'm not good in english, thank you for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

on session_start(), set a session variable to store the time:

```
$_SESSION['datetime_loggedin'] = time();
```

Then on session_destroy (just before the destroy), do this:

```
$difference = time() - $_SESSION['datetime_loggedin'];
```

then compare those to get the length of the session.

```
$session_length = gmdate("H:i:s", $difference);
```

Comment: That will only work if the session is terminated with a script (such as a logout script), not if it is abandoned. It would need a javascript widget to trigger on regular intervals to determine a fair estimate of the last time the page was open.

Answer (score 0):

When user logs in:

```
$start_time = time();
```

When user is about to leave:

```
$end_time = time();
$total_time = $start_time - $end_time;
```